# IBM MQ - MQ Client Connecting to a MQ Cluster

Tags: ibm-mq

I have an MQ cluster which has two full repository queue managers and two partial repository queue managers. A Java client needs to connect to this cluster and should PUT/GET messages. Which queue manager should I expose to the Java client, is it a queue manager from full repository or is it any one from partial repository? is there a kind of a pattern/anti-pattern/advantage/disadvantage exposing any of those?

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Regards,
Yasothar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One pattern that is so often used that it has been adopted as a full-fledged IBM MQ feature is known as a Uniform Cluster. It is so called because every queue manager in the cluster hosts the same queues, and so it does not matter which queue manager the client application connects to.

However, to answer your direct question, the client should be given a CCDT which contains entries for each queue manager that hosts a copy of the queue the client application is using. This could be EVERY queue manager in the cluster, as per the Uniform Cluster pattern, or just some of them. It does not need to be only partials or only full repository queue managers, but instead you are looking for those hosting the queue.

If you are not sure what that set of queue managers is, you could go to one of your full repository queue managers and type in the following MQSC command (using `runmqsc` or your favourite other MQSC tool):

```
DISPLAY QCLUSTER(name-of-queue-used-by-application) CLUSQMGR
```

and the resultant list will show the hosting queue manager names in the `CLUSQMGR` field.